# Not using unbestimmte/bestimmte article when referring to actions

Tags: grammar-identification

> WIr haben zu Hause eine Geige, dabei kann keiner in meiner Familie __ Geige spielen

According to the source where I got this exercise,  there should be no article in the blank. Could someone explain why? I have read [this post](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/59469/51342) and I think it maybe related, but I am not sure.  Is this also a stylistic choice?

Else, could someone explain the general principle behind this?

Answer (score 1):

> Wir haben zu Hause eine Geige, dabei kann keiner in meiner Familie Geige spielen.

That's the most common way to phrase it. That is because *Geige spielen* is a verb phrase as *Rad fahren*. It's not about a particular violine but about the ability to play violine.

BUT you could also say

> Wir haben zu Hause eine Geige, dabei kann keiner in meiner Familie die Geige spielen.

This is not super common but **also** not about that particular violine. The verb phrase *die Geige spielen* a more refined way to say *Geige spielen*. It is often phrased that way when it is about playing musical instruments.

On the other hand, no one says *das Rad fahren* when they don't mean a particular bicycle.

---

This is **again** one of those questions native speakers would get "wrong". Your materials are confusing.

Comment: Could you explain to me what exactly "verb phrases" are in German? I can't ind good explanations on the internet

Comment: Search for *Nomen-Verb-Verbindungen.*

Comment: I'd argue that in your 2nd example it is about that particular violin (thus definitive article) which is used as pars pro toto.

Comment: In the second example it can be either imo - it can refer to the particular violin or violins in general. One would have to phrase it differently  to make that distinction.

Comment: Beim Radfahren gibt es ein eigenes Substantiv - ich meine vor der Rechtschreibreform in Zusammensetzung aber nur ausnahmsweise üblich. Das Geigenspielen findet heute wg. gutem Wetter draußen statt. Hm.